# Why does WebApps warn me "you're in danger of being blocked" when I haven't asked any questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions

When I log into webapps I see this:

[image]

Here's my profile:

[image]

What has contributed to my warning being issued?  How do I find out?  I know this question has been asked before, but the ones I saw applied to people who *had* asked questions.

Answer (score 4):

You have asked two questions previously.

[image: Question List]

The [first question was asked on 28th October 2011](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20194/do-captchas-need-to-be-that-complicated) and was closed as not a real question.
The [second question was asked on 17th June 2014](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62626/what-is-the-most-reliable-way-to-play-an-embedded-sound-on-a-web-page) and was closed and migrated to StackOverflow as it was about programming.

Both of these questions have now been deleted. So overall your profile doesn't look that great 2 deleted questions, no answers and you have made one up vote.

This will be why you are seeing the warning :)

Comment: Ah. There's always deleted questions, aren't there? 100% closed and deleted and no positive score isn't good, but I'm surprised that it's tripping on only two posts.

Answer (score 3):

More than likely, someone who shares your network has been asking poorly-received questions.

From [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/21960)

> **My account is in good standing. Why am I still blocked?**
>
> The ban also takes in account the IP address. If you browse from a shared computer, or from a location that gives the same IP address to many end users, it's enough that another user who was banned or triggers the ban, will affect everyone else accessing from the same location.
>
> To help rectify this, browse from a different location.

Assuming you don't have a bunch of deleted questions, that seems the likeliest explanation.

Comment: Boy, that's really annoying.  I assume there is a whole bunch of people who share the IP address my ISP has assigned to me.  Does this ban warning only apply to WebApps ? (I don't seem to get the message from Stack Overflow).

Comment: Yes, it only applies to Web Apps. Further, the post ban is not currently turned on here, so even though you're getting the warning you're not in danger of being throttled.